# How can I get the last position of my Technical in this query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 table with data:

[image]

and

[image]

The table `Posicion`, save the posicion of each `Tecnico` some time.

I try to get the last `Posicion` of each `Tecnico` with this query.

```
Select Longitud, Latitude
From (Select idTecnico as id 
From Tecnico), Posicion
Where Posicion.idTecnico = id
Max(updated_at)
```

This query must return the rows 1 and 3 of the `Posicion` table (idPosicion 1 and 3)

but doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should return 1 and 3 given sample data, but will return the last posicion for all tecnico.

```
SELECT P.Longitud, P.Latitude, P.idTecnico
FROM Posicion P
INNER JOIN (Select max(Uptade_at) maxUptade_at, IdTechnico from Posicion group by IdTecnico) P2
on P.IDTecnico = P2.P.IdTecnico
and P.Uptade_at = maxUptade_at
```